# Postgresql extracting data

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have a query like

```
 <books>
  <book id='1'>
   <a>
    <b='1'>
     <book id='1.1'>abc</book>
     <book id='1.2'>abc1</book>
     <book id='1.3'>abc2</book>
    </b>
   </a>
  </book>
 </books>
```

Now I wanted a table with columns and data as below

```
bookId,bookName
1       NULL
1.1     abc
1.2     abc1
1.3     abc2
```

I tried using

```
xpath_table('id','<xml column>','table name''/books/book/@id|/books/book','true')
```

but I am getting

```
bookId bookName
1     abcabc1abc2
1.1   abc
1.2   abc1
1.3   abc2
```

please help me to get the desired result

Comment: This seems to work better, however I get an additional empty row: `xpath_table('id','<column_name>','<table_name>', '/books//book/@id|/books//book/text()','true')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think it's possible to fix it with criteria parameter (I just don't know PostgreSQL well enough) or just by where clause - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9388e/15

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah the output for book 1 should be null we are getting a value which is for book 1.1 when using text()